# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The function or procedure update_Faculty has too many arguments.'

Tags: c#, sql

I've been working a little with C# and SQL but I'm getting an error when executing my stored procedure to update the data in the database, here is my function that is called on a Click action

```
 public void UpdateFaculty() {

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Server=FS01-605484-PC\ROOT1;Database=School;Trusted_connection=true";

            SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand();

            //Update Sotred Procedure
            sqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlcommand.CommandText = "update_Faculty";
            sqlcommand.Connection = connection;

            //Parameters to be modified 
            sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pID_Faculty", int.Parse(lblID_Faculty.Text));
            sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCode", (txtCode.Text));
            sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pName", (txtName.Text));
            sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pCreation_Date", Convert.ToDateTime(txtCreationDate.Text));
            sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("pUniversity", int.Parse(ddlUniversity.SelectedValue));
            connection.Open();

            //Execute command on Database
            // The error is shown here
            sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();

        }

        #endregion Methods

    }
```

And here is my stored procedure in SQL

```
CREATE PROCEDURE update_Faculty
    -- I declare my variables to be modified 
    @pID_Faculty INT,
    @pCode VARCHAR(20),
    @pName VARCHAR(100),
    @pCreation_Date DATE,
    @pUniversity INT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Statements for procedure here
    UPDATE Faculty
    SET Code = @pCode,
        Name = @pName,
        Creation_date = @pCreation_Date,
        University = @pUniversity
    WHERE ID_Faculty = @pID_Faculty

END
```

Comment: are you *absolutely sure* that the stored proc is what you think it is? it is very easy to find that the stored proc on a particular server isn't what you have locally; it could also be that there are two versions of `update_Faculty` in different schemas - maybe `dbo.update_Faculty` vs `YourServiceUser.update_Faculty` - which could have different numbers of parameters; `YourServiceUser.update_Faculty` would be chosen in preference to `dbo.update_Faculty` if it exists

Comment: I see no problem whatsoever, could you check if that stored procedure matches with the one in the server?

Comment: @MarcGravell I've another 4 stored procedures implemented in the same way I'm trying to implement this one, and there is no problem, I also tried to delete the procedure and create it again, but I still get the error even if I change the name , at the time of debugging the application, the parameters I try to modify are stored correctly in the variables.

Comment: @bradbury9 Indeed it does, I also tryied to rename it in different ways but still not working.

Comment: Have you tried executing the sproc through SSMS and just passing the params in directly?

Comment: Delete the stored procedure and execute the code, the error message should change, if it does not you are not looking at the correct database